# Plot 3D histogram with uneven length array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Here is the sample codes

```
import numpy as np
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

a = floor(100*random(100)) # create 100 random point
b = floor(100*random(75))
c = floor(100*random(68))
  :
  :
n = floor(100*random(45))

data = [a, b, c, ..., n]
```

Now, I'd like to plot a 3D histogram on data whilst making the

```
x-axis : value
y-axis : count w.r.t. to the value
z-axis : ith row of data metrix
```

Either it shows the bar or 3D surface .  Your advice will be apprecited.

Comment: http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/WRT

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use [ax.bar3d](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d
import matplotlib.cm as cm

np.random.seed(3)

a = np.random.random_integers(100, size = (100, ))
b = np.random.random_integers(100, size = (75, ))
c = np.random.random_integers(100, size = (68, ))
n = np.random.random_integers(100, size = (45, ))
data = (a,b,c,n)
# data = np.random.random_integers(100, size = (4, 100))  # also possible
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = '3d')

for i, arr in enumerate(data):
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(arr, bins = 10)
    x = bin_edges[:-1]
    y = i*np.ones_like(hist)
    z = np.zeros_like(hist)
    dx = np.diff(bin_edges)
    dy = 0.01
    dz = hist
    color = cm.RdBu(float(i)/len(data))
    ax.bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color = color, alpha = 0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]